# Do Familiars provoke Attacks of Opportunity when delivering touch spells?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, familiars, touch-attacks

Now looking online I found this:

If the master is 3rd level or higher, a familiar can deliver touch spells for him. If the master and the familiar are in contact at the time the master casts a touch spell, he can designate his familiar as the "toucher." *The familiar can then deliver the touch spell just as the master could*. As usual, if the master casts another spell before the touch is delivered, the touch spell dissipates.

Can someone point me to something that explains whether or not they do provoke AOO in a rulebook?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 10):

#### The typical Tiny or littler familiar provokes an attack of opportunity for entering its foe's space, not for delivering the touch spell

The *Player's Handbook* on [Touch Attacks](http://dndsrd.net/actionsInCombat.html#touch-attacks), in part, says, "Touching an opponent with a touch spell is considered to be an armed attack and therefore does not provoke attacks of opportunity" (141). If the familiar [delivers the touch spell](http://dndsrd.net/wizard.html#familiar-deliver-touch-spell)'s charge "as the master could," the familiar likewise benefits from these rules.

However, keep in mind that many familiars *are* Tiny or littler therefore typically having reach 0 ft. and not threatening an area. Thus to deliver that touch spell's charge they must move typically into an opponent's space and doing that typically provokes an attack of opportunity (see *PH* 149 and [here](http://dndsrd.net/movement.html#big-and-little-creatures-in-combat)).